# How to interpret the N and R sections in SNOWTAM

Tags: snowtam

I am trying to decode this snowtam for 2 days now and I followed this [Snowtam Guideline](https://www.spilve.lv/library/meteo/SNOWTAM%20Harmonisation%20Guidelines.pdf).

So N is taxiway state and multiple taxiway states can be combined. R is apron state and multiple apron states can be combined. But in the example below, I cannot see how it makes sense. For example in R, are 1,2,3,4,6,7,East,North all apron names?

```
SWES0698 ESSB 12261815 COR
(SNOWTAM 0698
A) ESSB
B) 12261815 C) 12 F) 1/1/1 G) XX/XX/XX H) 5/5/5
N) G1 R S T Y Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4 Y5 YU YW/1/GOOD.
R) 1 2 3 4 6 7 EAST NORTH/1/GOOD
T) RWY 12 BA 67/72/67. RWY 12 COVER 100 PERCENT. APRON SANDED.)
CREATED: 26 DEC 2019 18:32:00 
SOURCE: EUECYIYN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, those are all apron names. You can see where they are on the [airport chart](https://www.aro.lfv.se/Editorial/View/6760/ES_AD_2_ESSB_2-1_en).

[image: Closeup of ramps on airport chart]